# clickable_links = driver.find_element()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to develop a python code to print list of all clickable elements but I'm getting error.

```
File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Find_clickables.py", line 9, in <module>
    clickable_links = driver.find_element()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\username\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 739, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
```

I tried below code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://google.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
# Find all clickable elements on page
clickable_links = driver.find_element()
for link in clickable_links:
    print(link)
```

Comment: But you didn't specify what are you trying to find. `driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_of_element")` if you want to search with id.

Comment: You have to pass arguments to `find_element()` to tell it WHAT ELEMENTS you're trying to find...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just listed all commonly used `html` tags, that are `interactive`, there are plenty more out there, and any widget can be stimulated as a “button” using JavaScript.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Set up webdriver (replace 'driver_path' with the path to your webdriver executable)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver_path')

# Open a webpage
driver.get('https://www.example.com')

# Find all <a> tags
a_tags = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

# Find all <li> tags
li_tags = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

# Find all <button> tags
button_tags = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')

# Find all clickable items (using CSS selector)
clickable_items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[onclick], [href], [type="submit"], [type="button"], [type="image"], [role="button"]')

# Print the results
print("Found", len(a_tags), "<a> tags:")
for tag in a_tags:
    print(tag.get_attribute('href'))

print("Found", len(li_tags), "<li> tags:")
for tag in li_tags:
    print(tag.text)

print("Found", len(button_tags), "<button> tags:")
for tag in li_tags:
    print(tag.text)

print("Found", len(clickable_items), "clickable items:")
for item in clickable_items:
    print(item.get_attribute('onclick'), item.get_attribute('href'), item.get_attribute('type'), item.get_attribute('role'))

# Close the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ApaxPhoenix! Appreciate your time.